# TypeError: unbound method collide() must be called with Enemy instance as first argument (got type instance instead) in processing 3.5.4

Tags: python, game-physics

I am getting this error whilst trying to add collision to a game and I have gotten this error for now all I want is for the game to print yes when the target is hit if there better way to detect collision I'm all ears. anything helps.

```
TypeError: unbound method collide() must be called with Enemy instance as first argument (got type instance instead)
```

This error comes from this code

```
Enemy.collide(Bullets)
```

this is the entire code ~200 lines

```
import math

class Spacey(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,siz,col):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.siz = siz
        self.col = col
        self.body_angle = -90
        self.enabled = True
    def see(self):
        self.move()
        self.render()
        
        
    def show(self):
        stroke(250)
        point(self.x,self.y)
        
    def move(self):
        if(keyPressed and key == CODED):
            if(keyCode == LEFT):
                self.x += (sin(radians(self.body_angle))*2)
            if(keyCode == RIGHT):
                self.x -= (sin(radians(self.body_angle))*2)
            if(keyCode == UP):
                self.y += (sin(radians(self.body_angle))*2)
            if(keyCode == DOWN):
                self.y -= (sin(radians(self.body_angle))*2)
           
            if(keyCode == SHIFT and self.enabled):
                bullet_repeat = Bullets(self.x,self.y,5,stroke(113,195,0))
                bullet.append(bullet_repeat)
                self.enabled = False
            else:
                self.enabled = True
    
    def render(self):
        pushMatrix()
        translate(self.x,self.y)
        stroke(113,195,0)
        strokeWeight(3)

        fill(177,255,72)
        beginShape()
        vertex(self.x,self.y-40)
        vertex(self.x-40,self.y+40)
        vertex(self.x+40,self.y+40)
        vertex(self.x,self.y-40)
        endShape()
        popMatrix()

class Bullets(object):
    def __init__ (self,x,y,siz,col):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.startX = int(x)
        self.startY = y
        self.siz = int(siz)
        self.col = col
        self.sx = x
    def sx():
        return int(self.x)
    def siza(self):
        return int(self.siz)
    def colo():
        stroke(113,195,0)
    
    def see(self):
        self.move()
        self.render()
        self.sx()
        
    def show(self):
        stroke(250)
        point(self.x,self.y)
        
    def move(self):
        self.y = self.y - 5
        for bullets in bullet:
                if ((self.x-self.startX)**2 + (self.y-self.startY)**2) > 1000000000:
                    bullet.remove(bullets)
    def render(self):
            pushMatrix()
            translate(self.x,self.y)
            stroke(113,195,0)
            
            
            beginShape()
            circle(self.x,self.y+10,5)
            endShape(CLOSE)
            popMatrix()


class Enemy(object):            
    def __init__(self,x,y,siz,col):
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = y
        self.speed = 2
        self.health = 1000
        self.siz = int(siz)
        self.col = col
            
    def see(self):
        self.move()
        self.render()
    
    
    def move(self):
        spd = 2
        bts = True       
        for i in range(0, 2, 500):
            self.x += 2
            if self.x == 500:
                self.x = 2
            
         
        
    def health(self):
        healthy = 20
        if collide == True:
            health -= 1
        if healthy == 0:
            next_level()
            healthy += 100
            
            
    
        
    def render(self):
        pushMatrix()
        translate(self.x,self.y)
        stroke(113,195,0)
        strokeWeight(3)

        fill(177,255,72)
        beginShape()
        vertex(self.x,self.y-40)
        vertex(self.x-40,self.y+40)
        vertex(self.x+40,self.y+40)
        vertex(self.x,self.y-40)
        endShape()
        popMatrix()
    def collide(self,other):    
         if(self.x + self.siz / 2 >= Bullets.sx() - Bullets.siz / 2 and self.x - self.siz / 2 <= Bullets.sx() + Bullets.siz / 2 
            and self.y + self.siz / 2 >= Bullets.y - Bullets.siza / 2 and self.y - self.siz / 2 <= Bullets.y + Bullets.siza / 2):
            print("YES")
        
def get_accuracy():
    for i in bullet:
        accuracy = hitcount / bcount 
        if accuracy >= 90:
            return 'AMAZING' 
        if accuracy >= 50:
            return 'GOOD' 
        if accuracy >= 10:
            return 'OKAY' 
        if accuracy < 10:
            print('NOT GOOD')

    




spacey = Spacey(250,400, 20,color(113,195,0))
enemy = Enemy(0,20,20,color(113,195,0))
bullet = []
collidesss = []
levels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def reset():
    spacey = spacey(250,400)
    enemy = enemy(0,20)
    
    
def setup():
    size(1000,1000)
    
def draw():
    global bcount, hitcount
    
    background(0,14,47)
    for bullet_repeat in bullet:
        bullet_repeat.see()
        
    spacey.see()
    enemy.see()
    for i in bullet:
        Enemy.collide(Bullets)
    
    
    hitcount = 0
    bcount = 0
    for bullet_repeat in bullet:
        bcount += 1
        
    
    
    fill(255)
    textSize(30)
    text(bcount,920,950,)
    text('Bullets shot:',730,950,)
```

This is now edited from the original

Comment: can you post the entire traceback? The class `bullets` has a `sx` attribute and a `sx` method, maybe that's the problem

Comment: You call in `def draw()` `enemy.collide(bullets)` with `bullets` which is a class. But the `collide` method expects as argument `other` an instance of `bullets` to call the instance method `sx`.

Comment: Capitalize your class-names and use lower-case for instances/variables. So you do not get mixed up. `enemy = enemy(0,20,20,color(113,195,0))` is a good example for this bad style.

Comment: I have made some edits which are now shown and the specific line of code that is giving a new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
for i in bullet:
    Enemy.collide(Bullets)
```

should be

```
for i in bullet:
    enemy.collide(Bullets)
```

`Enemy` is the class, `enemy` is an instance of the class.

In Python, class names are conventionally written with capital first letter, whereas instances/variables are written with lower case first letters.